# Relays connected in series?

Tags: voltage, relay, series

I have 2 identical relays (same specifications) whose working input voltage is 12V DC.

Can I connect the 2 relays in series by supplying 24V DC so that there will be 12V DC drop across each of the 2 relays?

What will be the behaviour of the relay coils, and the reverse coil voltages when connected in series?

[image: Relay in series]

Comment: what do you think the behavior will be?

Answer (score 4):

It will work fine if the relays have identical coil resistance. Each relay will see 12 V. When you open the circuit, each coil will see -0.7 V which is normal.

Note that you may have some very slight differences in the opening/closing times of each relay.

Answer (score 1):

As [JP314](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/595399/248404) said, If coils have same *resistance*, voltage will be divided equally. However, the *release time* of commutation will depend also of the *inductance* of each coil, that should be the same, otherwise the diodes used to protect the driving  transistor also can increase the release time to 3 ~5 times the specified release time. I posted [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/596220/248404) a table from *Zettler* manufacturer that compares different ways to protect the driver from the coil-induced voltage spike and its influence on the release time of the relay.

**About terminal numbering in relay** - it seems your relays are conventional auxiliary automotive relays, as I illustrated below, where they usually *don't have the protection diode*, as seen on the left side. On the right side, coil is paralleled with diode.
[image]
**In case protection diodes are external**: If relays are similar and do not have a built-in diode with the coil, you could *use just one diode* and connect the **K** diode Cathode to "86" of left relay and **A** diode Anode to "85" of right relay.

**Balancing coil currents and voltages**: A solution in case your two relays do not have equal resistance (as similar features from different brands, so *not equal relays*), the relay with higher resistance can receive a resistor in parallel to make it with the same equivalent resistance of the other one. This is a better approach in terms of current consumption:
[image]

An alternate "quick and dirty solution" to equalize the voltages is putting in parallel to each coil a *resistor* equal to the resistance of the *other* relay. Doing this, the equivalent resistance will become the same for each 12V relay assembly (coil+resistor+diode). Obviously, this second option will consume twice the original relay current, usually another hundred milliamps; just confirm if the power dissipation of each resistor is adequate.